# Error creating effect from memory (c++, directx 11)

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to create an effect variable from my compiled shader so I can reference variables and set their values but something is going wrong. I pulled a snippet from the **Introduction to 3D Game Programming** by Frank Luna and made tweaks where necessary

```
HRESULT hr;
DWORD shaderFlags = 0;
ID3D10Blob * compiledShader = 0;
ID3D10Blob * compilationMessages = 0;
hr = D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"cubemap.fx", 0, 0, 0, "fx_4_0", shaderFlags, 0, 0, &compiledShader, &compilationMessages, 0);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(nullptr,
        L"Failed to compile cubemap shader D3DX11", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return hr;
}
ID3DX11Effect * shader;
hr = D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory(
    compiledShader->GetBufferPointer(), compiledShader->GetBufferSize(), 0, device, &shader);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    MessageBox(nullptr,
        L"Could not create effect from memory", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return hr;
}
```

And it throws the error

```
Could not create effect from memory

HR = E_FAIL

Attempted to create a device with the debug layer enabled and the layer is not installed.
```

I've tried to debug a little and rebuild the effect libraries but still nothing. Could someone spot the issue or tell me how to go about finding the cause?

Edit: I believe the issue is with the debug layer. I have tried enabling the debug layer using (both D3D10 and D3D11)

```
#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined (DEBUG)
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG;
    shaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#endif
```

My device flags also enable debug mode

```
    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;

#if defined (_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio is using the Windows 8.1 SDK by default, but I am also referencing the old June 2010 SDK and this is where the problem is happening. The methods I am trying to use above are from the old SDK.

I believe all the requires dlls are installed for the debug layer.
[image]

I also have the dlls for the old sdk (the one I'm using to reference the old methods) [image]

**Solved**

I downloaded the latest version of Effects11 and compiled the shader with a compatible fx version (fx_5_0)

Comment: You're not telling us exactly what the value of `hr` is.

Comment: Your edit still does not tell us what `hr` is:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  The `FAILED` macro only tells us that `hr < 0`.

Comment: `Attempted to create a device with the debug layer enabled and the layer is not installed.`  So did the text of the actual error give you a little more detail than just a `FAILED(hr)`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did a little reading on it and made some alterations but it's still happening. The device flags also enable the debug mode. Is there anything I need to install?

Comment: Still not solved, anything I seem to try always produces this error. When I remove the CreateEffectFromMemory function call, everything works fine.

Comment: You should start by getting the latest version of Effects 11 from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11). Second, make sure your project is using the correct include order for mixing the old legacy DirectX SDK with the Windows 8.1 SDK. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling the latest version of Effects 11 seemed to solve the issue.